# jquery function is looping twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

Each value of my json object is getting added to "listOfCountries" twice.  I don't understand why it would be looping through the result object twice.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
var listOfCountries = []

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Json/GetCountries',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {

            $.each(result, function (name, value) {
                listOfCountries.push(value.Country);
            });

            $("#countriesAutoComplete").kendoAutoComplete(listOfCountries);
        }
    });
});
```

Json object being sent over the wire:

```
[{"Country": "United States Of America"},{"Country": "Australia"},{"Country": "Britain"}]
```

html

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       <p>
           Country: <input id="countriesAutoComplete" class="k-input" />
       </p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your function.Try putting `console.log` in `$.each` function to make sure its executing twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your code runs, you add more strings to `listOfCountries`.
You never remove the strings from last time, so the global array keeps growing.

You probably shouldn't make it a global variable.